# MySQL - Updating the same value causes slowdown

Tags: php, mysql

we're currently invastigating an issue on our project with dozens of thousands of site calls. It seems like the problem is, that when visitors get on our site, it updates one specific value but that over and over.

That value is the calling of an ad campaign banner for a customer whose value "impressions" is increased with every site call. As it's only one campaign, it is updated thousands of times per day and seems to slow down the server. One of the thoughts was, that it might be, that because all visitors increase that value with every page load, it gets stuck in a queue until eventually slowing down completely. Is that possible?

What measurements can we do to stop the slowdown? Can we increase and or test a MySQL limit? And if yes, which would it be?
Or will only upgrading the server help?

I have only limited access and knowledge to this so I won't be able to give server-specific answers.

Comment: Yes, the table might be locking which would queue all other queries. Are you using myisam or innodb? Have you looked at the process list when the slow down occurs? This seems like a DB question, not PHP.

Comment: We are using MySQL. That's all I know.

Comment: Run `show create table ....` on the table you are inserting/updating. Use `show full process list` when the slow down occurs next.

Comment: Where do I have to enter this in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, you could run it there.. or you could run it as an auxiliary script

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it probable? No.

In MyISAM, an update or delete query will lock the table so any other processes on that same table could also be locking and building up a queue. In InnoDB, it's a little more complex depending on your indexes, but updates tend to be more row-specific in their locks.

If you're simply updating a counter in a table that doesn't have many rows then chances are that the query would execute so quickly that you wouldn't be building up a queue. You would need an overwhelming number of visitors very quickly to generate that kind of build-up. Think of it this way - it the uodate query runs in 10 milliseconds, then you would generally need to have a visitor every 9 milliseconds to have a queue.

So if you do have an overwhelming number of visitors, you might consider just inserting a new record into some impressions table, and then run a select count() on that impressions table. That should work smoother than updating a counter.

Also, one other possibility is that your PHP script could be establishing persistent connections that are sticking around instead of closing, and that could result in a slow starvation of resources and eventually an exhaustion of connections. We'd have to see your code to be sure and it would help to see your table description and process list as someone else mentioned.

Comment: I'm not able to show code due to my limited access to it. But what I know is, that we multiple times got an error with too many connections. So this might be something to look into. And yes, we receive alot of traffic at the same time. So let's say an "extreme example": I have 2.500 users trying to update X at the same time - it slows down. When I now would start counting the same campaign but through table "campaign_views" and with mysqli_num_rows() for example, it would work without problems?

Comment: No, not in your extreme example. With that many simultaneous users and that error message, your problem is more likely infrastructure. You should be certain about these numbers because the higher the number of simultaneous users, the more hardware is required, and the higher the chance of growth. For 2500 users, I would make sure to have at least 32 GB of RAM. You probably need to set max_connections to 2500. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/11/28/mysql-error-too-many-connections/ for some tips

Comment: Given my last comment, an insert + count() approach still has a better chance of avoiding issues due to locking and you should still ensure you're using InnoDB for your tables (which is overall faster than MyISAM tables these days and more capable, too). With that many users, you might also want to start considering / planning to move to MySQL cluster so you can scale with growth.